# Python for loops and data

Tags: python, for-loop

I have data that looks like this:

The columns are Name, ID, Dev ID, Date

```
('Anthony', '1', '10', '4/3/2017')
('Anthony', '1', '11', '5/2/2017')
('Anthony', '1', '13', '12/30/2017
('Anthony', '1', '15', '8/20/2017'
('Anthony', '4', '17', '2/3/2018')
('Anthony', '4', '18', '3/28/2017'
('Bob', '1', '111', '4/3/2017')
('Bob', '1', '200', '5/2/2017')
('Bob', '1', '113', '12/30/2017')
('Bob', '1', '115', '8/20/2017')
('Bob', '4', '117', '2/3/2018')
('Bob', '4', '118', '3/28/2017')
```

I'm trying to find unique Name's and ID's and then compare any dates and return only the one furthest in the future.

Ideally I want output that looks like:

```
('Anthony', '1', '12/30/2017')
('Anthony', '4', '2/3/2018')
('Bob', '1', '12/30/2017')
('Bob', '4', '2/3/2018')
```

I'm struggling because I have multiple keys and I can't figure out how to make it work. Any ideas?

Edit: This is only a sample I have 30ish people names and 10 unique id's. So i'm looking to make a For loop to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` combined with `max` to get output similar to what you're looking for.

```
import itertools
from datetime import datetime

data = [('Anthony', '1', '10', '4/3/2017'),
         ('Anthony', '1', '11', '5/2/2017'),
         ('Anthony', '1', '13', '12/30/2017'),
         ('Anthony', '1', '15', '8/20/2017'),
         ('Anthony', '4', '17', '2/3/2018'),
         ('Anthony', '4', '18', '3/28/2017'),
         ('Bob', '1', '111', '4/3/2017'),
         ('Bob', '1', '200', '5/2/2017'),
         ('Bob', '1', '113', '12/30/2017'),
         ('Bob', '1', '115', '8/20/2017'),
         ('Bob', '4', '117', '2/3/2018'),
         ('Bob', '4', '118', '3/28/2017')]

groups_with_max_date = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(data, lambda d: (d[0], d[1])):
    # convert to datetime and get max of group
    group_max = max(group, key=lambda q: datetime.strptime(q[3], '%m/%d/%Y'))
    groups_with_max_date.append(group_max)

groups_with_max_date
```

Gives us:

```
[('Anthony', '1', '13', '12/30/2017'),
 ('Anthony', '4', '17', '2/3/2018'),
 ('Bob', '1', '113', '12/30/2017'),
 ('Bob', '4', '117', '2/3/2018')]
```

Comment: This will only work if the columns are sorted by "Name" and "Id"

Comment: You could use [```operator.itemgetter(0,1)```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the key to sort and groupby ```data```.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `datetime` object, `dict.setdefault()`, `max` and `datetime.strptime` functions:

```
import datetime

l = [('Anthony', '1', '10', '4/3/2017'),('Anthony', '1', '11', '5/2/2017'),('Anthony', '1', '13', '12/30/2017'),('Anthony', '1', '15', '8/20/2017'),
('Anthony', '4', '17', '2/3/2018'),('Anthony', '4', '18', '3/28/2017'),('Bob', '1', '111', '4/3/2017'),('Bob', '1', '200', '5/2/2017'),
('Bob', '1', '113', '12/30/2017'),('Bob', '1', '115', '8/20/2017'),('Bob', '4', '117', '2/3/2018'),('Bob', '4', '118', '3/28/2017')]

d = {}
for t in l:
    # grouping items by first two values of each tuple(accumulating `date` strings) 
    d.setdefault(t[0] +'-'+ t[1], []).append(t[3]) # first two values of a tuple are combined to be a "hash" key

# getting max date from the list of `datetime` objects
result = [(*k.split('-'), max(v, key=lambda dt: datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%m/%d/%Y'))) for k,v in sorted(d.items())]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('Anthony', '1', '12/30/2017'), ('Anthony', '4', '2/3/2018'), ('Bob', '1', '12/30/2017'), ('Bob', '4', '2/3/2018')]
```